# setImageResource causes animation not to work

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I'm facing problems with Animations and setting image resource.

I want to change the Image of an ImageView after a TranslateAnimation has finished, but doing this causes the Animation not to work anymore...

Heres my code:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, infoBoxLeft - infoBoxOffset, 0, 0);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(millis);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);

            infoBox.layout(infoBoxLeft - infoBoxOffset, infoBox.getTop(), (infoBoxLeft - infoBoxOffset)
                    + infoBoxWidth, infoBox.getTop() + infoBox.getHeight());

            infoBox.clearAnimation();

        }
    });

    infoBox.startAnimation(anim);
```

if I remove the line `arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);` everything works fine, with it the animation is not running.
I already tried using `setImageDrawable` (because documentation says it's not running on the UI-Thread) instead but no difference.
I also tried to call `setImageResource` outside the callback, before/after `startAnimation`.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.